# SWT Composite not showing up after java update

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

We recently had our Eclipse upgraded from Helios to Kepler, and our JDK from 7 to 8. The application had banners on the top and bottom, but ever since the update they don't show up anymore. I didn't work on this part of the code, and it's the my first tome looking at it, so I'm not familiar with it. The topBanner, bottomBanner and corresponding lables show up. Some methods show up as deprecated

```
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createMenuBar //replaced with new Menu(shell)
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createCoolBarControl // replaced with new CoolBar(shell, someColor);
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createPageComposite // don't know what to replace it with
```

Making these updates did not make any visible change in the application. Here is my application code:

```
private static Composite topBanner,bottomBanner;
private Control toolbar;
private Control page;
private static Label topLabel,bottomLabel;
private int labelBackgroundColor=SWT.COLOR_YELLOW;

public static void setClassificationLabelColor(Color barColor)
{
    int fontColor = SWT.COLOR_WHITE;
    if (barColor.getGreen() == 255) {
        fontColor = SWT.COLOR_BLACK;
    }
    topBanner.setBackground(barColor);
    topLabel.setBackground(barColor);
    topLabel.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(fontColor));
    bottomBanner.setBackground(barColor);
    bottomLabel.setBackground(barColor);
    bottomLabel.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(fontColor));
    topBanner.layout();
    bottomBanner.layout();
}

public static void setClassificationLabelText(String text)
{
    if (text == null) { text = ""; }
    topLabel.setText(text);
    bottomLabel.setText(text);
    topBanner.layout();
    bottomBanner.layout();
}

public void createWindowContents(Shell shell)
{
    GridLayout gl;
    GridData gd;
    IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    String defaultBanner = String.valueOf(SystemDAO.getDefaultBannerClassification(SystemDAO.MAIN_ROW_ID));

    //top banner
    topBanner = new Composite(configurer.getWindow().getShell(), 0);
    topBanner.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(labelBackgroundColor));
    gd=new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    gd.heightHint=12;
    topBanner.setLayoutData(gd);
    gl=new GridLayout();gl.marginTop=-6;
    topBanner.setLayout(gl);

    //top label
    topLabel=new Label(topBanner,SWT.None);
    topLabel.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(labelBackgroundColor));
    topLabel.setText(defaultBanner);
    topLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER,SWT.BOTTOM,true,false));

    //menu
    org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu menu = configurer.createMenuBar(); //deprecated**
    shell.setMenuBar(menu);

    //tool bar
    toolbar = configurer.createCoolBarControl(shell); //deprecated**
    ((CoolBar)toolbar).setLocked(true);
    toolbar.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));

    //page
    page = configurer.createPageComposite(shell); //deprecated**
    page.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

    //bottom banner
    bottomBanner = new Composite(configurer.getWindow().getShell(), 0);        
    bottomBanner.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(labelBackgroundColor));        
    gd=new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    gd.heightHint=12;
    bottomBanner.setLayoutData(gd);
    gl=new GridLayout();gl.marginTop=-6;
    bottomBanner.setLayout(gl);

    //bottom label
    bottomLabel=new Label(bottomBanner,SWT.None);
    bottomLabel.setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(labelBackgroundColor));
    bottomLabel.setText(defaultBanner);
    bottomLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER,SWT.BOTTOM,true,false));

    //status bar
    Control statusLine=configurer.createStatusLineControl(configurer.getWindow().getShell());
    gd=new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    statusLine.setLayoutData(gd);

    createProgressIndicator((Composite)statusLine);
}

private void createProgressIndicator(Composite parent) {
    if (getWindowConfigurer().getShowProgressIndicator()) {
        WorkbenchWindow window = (WorkbenchWindow) getWindowConfigurer().getWindow();
        progressRegion = new ProgressRegion();
        progressRegion.createContents(parent, window);
    }
}
@Override
public void postWindowCreate() {
    /* removes unwanted IDE contribution items from the toolbar */
    IActionBarConfigurer actionBarConfigurer = getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer();
    IContributionItem[] coolItems = actionBarConfigurer.getCoolBarManager().getItems();

    for (int i=0; i < coolItems.length; i++) {
        if (coolItems[i] instanceof ToolBarContributionItem) {
            ToolBarContributionItem toolbarItem = (ToolBarContributionItem) coolItems[i];
            if (toolbarItem.getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet") || //$NON-NLS-1$
                    toolbarItem.getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation") || //$NON-NLS-1$
                    toolbarItem.getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation")||
                    toolbarItem.getId().equals("org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet")||
                    toolbarItem.getId().equals("org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet")) { //$NON-NLS-1$
                toolbarItem.getToolBarManager().removeAll();
            }
        }
    }

    actionBarConfigurer.getCoolBarManager().update(true);

    //have the application window initially maximized
    getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell().setMaximized(true);
}
```

I've been trying to fix this for two days, but I'm not very familiar with SWT. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What class is this class extending?

Comment: WorkbenchWindowAdvisor

Comment: Is `createWindowContents` being called at all? The deprecation comment for this method say 'This method is no longer used. Applications now define workbench window contents in their application model.'

Comment: It wasn't! Noob mistake I guess. I added it, but now both my top and bottom banner are at the bottom of the application, and the rest of the application only takes about 25% of the entire window. I think this is something I can try and fix myself. Thanks!

Comment: The deprecation comment is really saying that you should not be trying to do things this way anymore. Fundamental changes to the look of Eclipse 4 apps should be done in the e4xmi application model even for 3.x compatibility apps. Also why are you only switching to Kepler, this is already pretty old.

Comment: It wasn't my decision. It was a security concern at the company.

Comment: So both my banners show up at the bottom of the app. Any ideas on how to have one at the top and the other in the bottom? Can't seem to figure it out.